# Define a method for record in vhdl

Tags: methods, record, vhdl, xilinx

Is is possible to define something like OOP-style instance method for a record in VHDL to be recognized by XST?

For a record type **rectangle**:

```
type rectangle is record
    x      : integer;
    y      : integer;
    width  : integer;
    height : integer;
end record;
```

I'd like to define methods like **is_square**, **get_area**, etc.

Can it be done using attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can get close with `protected` types.

Here's an example, taken from [Protected Shared Variables in VHDL: IEEE Std 1076a](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=622937)

```
type shared_counter is protected body
     variable count : integer := 0;
     procedure reset is
     begin
         count := 0;
     end procedure reset;
     procedure increment (by : integer := 1) is
     begin
         count := count + by;
     end procedure increment;
     impure function value return integer is
     begin
         return count;
     end function value;
end protected body shared_counter;
```

I have no idea if the concept of a protected type is synthesisable with XST though.

Comment: hm. they look object-oriented. Have you tried them by yourself (with which synthesizer)?
Also I found that protected types are not supported in ISim http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/33123.htm

Comment: Yes, they are quite OO.  I've used them in simulation with Modelsim.  And now you come to mention it, I *have* tried them with ISIM, and, yes, it choked on them :(

Answer (score 3):

Is there some reason you don't want to simply define a few functions along with your custom type(s)?

In addition to defining new functions (such as your is_square, above), you can override existing functions (such as +, <, etc) if that makes sense for your code.

Normally, you'd wrap your custom types and the functions to manipulate them into a package you'd then use in your code.  See for example the standard VHDL math_real and numeric_std packages.

Comment: the reason is that such approach doesn't look like OOP. It looks more natural when calling my_std_logic_vector'length built-in attribute instead of get_length(my_std_logic_vector)